# Show that the elements of the form $1+\zeta + \zeta^2 + \dots + \zeta^m$, with $1 \leq m \leq p-2$, are invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> Let $\zeta = e^\frac{2 \pi i}{p}$, with $p$ prime. Show that the elements of the form $1+\zeta +\zeta^2 + \dots + \zeta^m$, with $1 \leq m \leq p-2$, are invertible in $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$.

I know that $f(\zeta) \in \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is invertible if and only if $N(f(\zeta)) \in \{1, -1\}$.

**Definition :** $N(f\zeta)) = \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} \sigma_i(f(\zeta)) = \prod_{i=1}^{p-1} f(\zeta^i) $ and $\sigma_m(f(\zeta)) = f(\zeta^m) $

This doesn't make sense for me because $|\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} f(\zeta^i)| > 1 $.
I already know that $1+\zeta +\zeta^2 + \dots + \zeta^m = \frac{\zeta^{m-1}-1}{\zeta-1}$, but it not clear this expression could help me.

Is anyone could give me a hint how to solve this problem?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true, $N(1+\zeta_4) = 1+1 = 2$

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: $4$ is not prime...

Comment: Ah, very true. Maybe something like $N(1+\zeta_5) = \frac 1 2 (1+\sqrt 5)$. Note that the statement is definitely true if $m=p-2$

Comment: $(1+\zeta_5)(-\zeta_5^3 - \zeta_5) = 1$

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish: $N$ here is the norm for the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$, not the complex absolute value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s see whether I can get this right.

The key is, indeed, your observation that your quantity is equal to $(\zeta_p^{m+1}-1)\big/(\zeta_p-1)$. Now, in accordance with your observation about the norms, all you need to do is show that the norm here is equal to $1$. But $\zeta_p^{m+1}-1$ and $\zeta_p-1$ have the same norm (down to $\Bbb Q$) as long as $m+1<p$, because $\zeta_p$ and $\zeta_p^{m+1}$ are conjugate over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: Oh, conjugate elements always have the same norm. And $\zeta^{m+1}$ and $\zeta$ have the same minimal polynomial, so are conjugate.